# Why is this URL like this in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I was under the impression that every View in your application has it's own unique URL. For example:

Home/Index
Home/Test
Home/Error
Home/Help

In my Upload controller I call on the Error view. Yet the URL stays on what it was before, not changing to reflect the error url.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
    {
        if (excelFile != null)
        {
            *Snip for brevity, everything is peachy here.*

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Error");
        }            
    }
```

Any suggestions why this is the case?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Shouldn't the URL be /Upload/Error? Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Tested by creating a new view called Test and the same results. The Test view displays but the URL stays on /Upload/Index. :(

Comment: I guess I'm just curious why this is happening. Every thing in programming has a reason, I'm just not seeing it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs do not map to Views.

URLs map to Controller actions.

See this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

If you want a URL of /Upload/Error

You could make:

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
    {
        if (excelFile != null)
        {
            *Snip for brevity, everything is peachy here.*

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error","Upload");
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the content of the View. If you want the URL to change, you need to RedirectToAction()

Comment: Now it's saying Not all code paths return a value; because on one end of the if statement I'm not returning an ActionResult() - any suggestion? :)

Comment: You have to say
  return RedirectToAction("Error","Upload");.

Comment: @Daveo: That's what I'm doing. :\

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL to change to /Upload/Error, here's what you would add to your UploadController:

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then, instead of returning the Error view, you would call: `return RedirectToAction("Error","Upload");`.

This basically shows the difference between controllers, actions, and views - **controller actions can return any view they want (or other ActionResult) to a request, but only on one URL, unless they "reroute" the request to another action.**

Comment: Now it's saying Not all code paths return a value; because on one end of the if statement I'm not returning an ActionResult() - any suggestion? :)

Comment: @SergioTapia: The way I'd do it is to just put the `RedirectToAction` without an else block around it. If the `return View();` is called, the processing isn't going to get to the RedirectToAction line, so it'll work correctly.

Comment: @SergioTapia: Are you sure? It really shouldn't be giving you that error, even with the original code, because if and else cover all code paths. Is that the whole code you have? Can you try to recompile?

Comment: you DO have the word "return"

Comment: @Maxim Zaslavsky: No, I didn't have the return. Christ. Time for a coffee break. :P

Comment: @SergioTapia: Glad you fixed that. Those things happen to the best of us, and it's always hard to track down those nasty little bugs. Enjoy that coffee! :D

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC every URL maps to a controller/action. So you can return whatever view from your controller action, this doesn't change the URL.

If you want to redirect to an error Page, then either include a `ErrorController` in your project or an Error action in your `FileUploadController` and then do a Redirect to the appropriate action:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult FileUploadError()
    {
        return View(); //returns view "FileUploadError"
    }
}

public class FileUploadController : Controller // the controller you use to upload your files
{
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(); //return view "Error"
    }

    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)  // action from your post
    {
        //... do the upload stuff
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error"); // if you want to use the Error action in this controller;
            // or
            return RedirectToAction("FileUploadError", "Error"); // if you want to use the action on the ErrorController
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my comments to the answer above. I get a Not All Code Paths Return a Value error.

Comment: Did you include the `return`in front of RedirectToAction(...) ?